# How does Mule API Console work?

Tags: javascript, api, mule, esb

Does anyone know where the web content of the API Console is located - I would expect the css, html and js to be bundled in the app, where does the api console get these files from?

Comment: Do you mind adding an answer and accepting it? Or just close your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered Here: http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/api-console-where-is-the-web-content?rfm=1

(It is within the APIKit libs)